What are the criteria to consider two countries sea neighbours?
What are the criteria for two countries to be considered sea neighbours?
For example: Why are India and Maldives neighbours but not India and Indonesia?

That's a good question, not sure there is any universally agreed definition, where have you read this? Indonesia is certainly very close to the Nicobar islands…

For what purpose?

Needs more details.  Why do you suppose India and Indonesia are not considered "sea neighbours"

Hi @JamesK Let me extend the question. Why are India and the USA not considered as sea neighbours? There's a straight line that connects India with US across the oceans.

Let me repeat my request.  Who says India and the USA are not sea neighbours.  They seem to be sea neighours to me as you can travel from one to the other without passing through any other territorial waters.

Is "sea neighbor" really a thing? I haven't been able to find any uses of this. When I search in Google Ngrams, all the hits are part of larger phrases, like "land and sea neighbors" or "South China Sea neighbors". Neighbors are just countries that are near each other, and the borders can be either on land or sea.

India and USA are not sea neighbors because they're not neighbors at all. Neighbors have to be near each other.

Wikipedia has a List of countries and territories by land and maritime borders in which both Maldives and Indonesia are considered "maritime neighbors" of India.

For purposes of this list, "maritime boundary" includes boundaries that are recognized by the United Nations Convention on the Law of the Sea, which includes boundaries of territorial waters, contiguous zones, and exclusive economic zones.

